# Insert valid records from SP into valid table and Invalid records into Invalid SP

Tags: oracle, join, stored-procedures, inner-join, insert-update

I have two stored procedures, which filter the records on the table and give the result. The below are the stored procedures.

```
SELECT distinct  TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) AS SPAN_ID
               , TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
from  APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
INNER JOIN APP_FTTX.transmedia@SAT tm  -- transmedia added
on sp.RJ_SPAN_ID = tm.RJ_SPAN_ID
WHERE length(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = length(tm.RJ_SPAN_ID)
and sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = tm.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE
and sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = tm.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE
AND LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21
AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPN%') 
     OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPQ%') 
     OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPR%')    
     OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPS%'))
AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_BU') 
     OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_MP'))
AND sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
AND sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01'
AND (sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' 
     OR sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL);
```

The above SP returns 4 records and these are the valid records which I want to be inserted into a table.

Now there is another SP which is below which returns 7 records.

```
SELECT distinct  TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) AS SPAN_ID
               , TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
from  APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
-- INNER JOIN APP_FTTX.transmedia@SAT tm  -- transmedia added
--  on sp.RJ_SPAN_ID = tm.RJ_SPAN_ID
-- WHERE length(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = length(tm.RJ_SPAN_ID)
--  and sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = tm.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE
--   and sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = tm.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE
WHERE LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21
AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPN%') 
     OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPQ%') 
     OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPR%')    
     OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPS%'))
AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_BU') 
     OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_MP'))
AND sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
AND sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01'
AND (sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' 
     OR sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL);
```

The SP's are similar. There are 3 records which are invalid in second SP. SO what I want is this: I want to insert the other 3 records which are invalid into another table.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

According to Alex comment, I have achieved the minus part in my below code.

```
SELECT distinct  TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) AS SPAN_ID, TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
                                    from  APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
                                   -- INNER JOIN APP_FTTX.transmedia@SAT tm  -- transmedia added
                                  --  on sp.RJ_SPAN_ID = tm.RJ_SPAN_ID
                                   -- WHERE length(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = length(tm.RJ_SPAN_ID)
                                  --  and sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = tm.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE
                                 --   and sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = tm.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE
                                    WHERE LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21
                                    AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPN%') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPQ%') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPR%')    
                                    OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPS%'))
                                    AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_BU') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_MP'))
                                    AND sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
                                    AND sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01'
                                    AND (sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' OR sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL)                                        
            MINUS

       SELECT distinct  TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) AS SPAN_ID, 
          TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
                                    from  APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
                                    INNER JOIN APP_FTTX.transmedia@SAT tm  -- 
                transmedia added
                                     on sp.RJ_SPAN_ID = tm.RJ_SPAN_ID
                                    WHERE length(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 
               length(tm.RJ_SPAN_ID)
                                    and sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 
              tm.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE
                                    and sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 
              tm.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE
                                    AND LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21
                                    AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPN%') OR 
                sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPQ%') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPR%')    
                                        OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPS%'))
                                    AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_BU') OR 
               sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_MP'))
                                    AND sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
                                    AND sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 
              'INMUNVMB01'
                                    AND (sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE 
               ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' OR sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL);
```

Comment: You haven't shown any stored procedures, just queries. I'm not quite sure what you're asking - are you perhaps just looking for [`minus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html)?

Comment: @AlexPoole: yes i am looking for that with the records to be inserted in their respective tables as mentioned. Do u have any idea. And the above query I will convert it in procedures

Comment: Maybe not mention stored procedures if it's not relevant to the code you actually posted?

Comment: @APC: yes, i m sorry for that. The logic of converting it into SP was in mind. so while posting the question, i didnt got any another similar word for that

Comment: @AlexPoole: any help how to implement this ?

Comment: You can either write a new query that modifies the predicates such that it only returns those three records; or you can MINUS the two existing queries to get the difference between them - see the documentation I linked to before. Either way then use that as `insert ... select`.

Comment: Just as a side observation, I notice that all table references are to a db link - the same db link.  This seems rather odd.  I'd more expect perhaps one of the tables to be remote but not both (all) of them. Why not run the queries in the SAT database to begin with?  There could be legit reasons for what you are doing there, but I smell a misunderstanding on the use of db links.

Comment: @AlexPoole: i have tried and updated the question. Can u help me with the insert of valid and invalid records

Comment: So.... does that new minus query give you the three rows you expect? I'm not sure what help you want on top - doesn't `insert into ... select ...` do what you want?

Comment: @AlexPoole: yes I got the 3 rows after using minus. Now I want this 3 rows to be inserted into the a table with datetime.

Comment: @AlexPoole: kindly let me know if any steps or link provided that will also do

Comment: @AlexPoole: any update sir ? or should I ask for new question on this ?

Comment: What is the point of the `TO_CHAR` in your column list?  Aren't those ID's already strings? Are they `NCHAR`s?

Comment: @Del : nope. They are already strings..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off doing a `LEFT JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT sp.RJ_SPAN_ID AS SPAN_ID,
                sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE,
                SYSDATE AS MSG_DATE
FROM   APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
WHERE  LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21
AND REGEXP_LIKE(sp.rj_span_id, 'SP(N|Q|R|S).*_(BU|MP)$')
AND sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
AND sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01'
AND NVL(INSTR(sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID, '_'), 1) > 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                FROM APP_FTTX.transmedia@SAT tm
                WHERE tm.rj_span_id = sp.rj_span_id
                AND tm.rj_maintenance_zone_code = sp.rj_maintenance_zone_code
                AND tm.inventory_status_code = sp.inventory_status_code);
```

Notice the `NULL` check on `tm.rj_span_id`.  That is a column that should be guaranteed to be populated given our other logic.  Since it is `NULL`, we know a match wasn't found.

I've also made a few other tweaks:

1. There is no use in doing `length(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = length(tm.RJ_SPAN_ID)` in the bottom section.  You already checked that the values are equal during the `JOIN`.  If their values are equal, the length must be the same.
2. Think about using `REGEXP_LIKE` to simplify your logic.  Something like `REGEXP_LIKE(sp.rj_span_id, 'SP(N|Q|R|S).*_(BU|MP)$')`
3. Removed the `TO_CHAR` in the column list.  As discussed in the comments, they are already strings.
4. I changed your `NOT LIKE` and `IS NULL` to use `NVL` AND `INSTR`, but that is just more my preference (I've been playing [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and it has affected my brain)

As for your `INSERT`, just append that `SELECT` to an `INSERT INTO table_name` and you're all set. Like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO log_table_name
  SELECT DISTINCT sp.RJ_SPAN_ID AS SPAN_ID,
                  sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE,
                  SYSDATE AS UPDATED_DATE,
                  'YOUR_USERNAME' AS USERNAME
  FROM   APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
  WHERE  LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(sp.rj_span_id, 'SP(N|Q|R|S).*_(BU|MP)$')
  AND sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
  AND sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01'
  AND NVL(INSTR(sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID, '_'), 1) > 0
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                  FROM APP_FTTX.transmedia@SAT tm
                  WHERE tm.rj_span_id = sp.rj_span_id
                  AND tm.rj_maintenance_zone_code = sp.rj_maintenance_zone_code
                  AND tm.inventory_status_code = sp.inventory_status_code);
```

Note: I hardcoded the `UPDATED_BY` column as I don't know the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Del, it would be great if you can update the insert into table query also. That’s where I was mostly stuck. Even though I have the answer, would like to see your way of logic

Comment: @nkb Can you provide the table name and structure?

Comment: Yes, you can get the table name and it’s structure from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/61126310/1216804

Comment: @nkb That should help.  I'm not sure where you're pulling the `UPDATED_DATE` or `UPDATED_BY` columns so I put placeholders in for you.

Comment: Thanks Del, I would test it and get back to you. Would be needing more help in future.

Comment: U haven't checked the `MINUS` part in my query. Did u applied that ?

Comment: @nkb As I mentioned in my answer, I don't think that it is necessary.  From what I saw in your question, you were basically running a query.  Then running the same query, except performing an `INNER JOIN` to another table.  Then taking the difference.  This would leave only rows which didn't have matching records in the second table.  I achieve the same functionality by performing a `LEFT JOIN` and checking which rows don't have a corresponding row int the right table.

Comment: Ohh ok.  I will update you soon. Thanks for explaining:)

Comment: @nkb And actually, we could probably improve performance by not doing a `LEFT JOIN` and instead performing a `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: So if u can update it with that, it would be much greater. As improving performance will be the key

Comment: @nkb I made the switch.  In general this is preferable because it allows Oracle to stop searching once it finds one match in the second table.  There's a good askTOM article on it somewhere.

Comment: canu give me that link. ? I will update u on the above query in just a bit

Comment: it took 175 seconds to execute the query. can we reduce it more ?

Comment: pls let me know once u back. need one small change related to this code code.

Comment: @nkb There are a few ways to improve the performance.  First and foremost, double check that you still need that `DISTINCT` clause on the select.  If you don't, that will save you some.  After that, you can try some optomizer hints like `/*+ PARALLEL */` or `/*+ APPEND */` or both.  Read up on them first to see if they are what you need [(Oracle Doc Link)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#sthref482).  Lastly, if this is going to be run multiple times, run it again.  The first time will take longer while the optomizer parses the query.

Comment: can u come on chat. there we can discuss more clearly https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211367/discussion-between-del-and-nkb

Comment: hi, now while calling this SP, getting error as `ora-22804 remote operations not permitted on object tables or user-defined columns`

Comment: Are you inserting this information back across the DB Link too?  If so, I think @EdStevens has a point in the comments.  You probably should be doing this work on the SAT database instead of trying remotely.  Also, per the error, did you add user defined type columns to the insert? Or is the remote table an object table?

Comment: please come over chat for more discussion

Comment: also, i m not inserting on the DB link. its just i am inserting in my local flat table. till last friday it was working,but today it gave me error

Comment: i guess its due to `X` columns in the table. may be i should define the exact column name ?