# Error(9,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement while creating stored procedures

Tags: oracle, join, stored-procedures

I have created a SP, but while compiling I am getting error as

> Error(9,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Below is the SP

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIP_VALID_TBL_TRANSMEDIA 
 (
   POUTMSG OUT VARCHAR2
  )

 AS 
BEGIN

 SELECT distinct  TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) AS SPAN_ID, TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
                                    from  APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
                                    WHERE LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21
                                    AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPN%') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPQ%') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPR%')    
                                    OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPS%'))
                                    AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_BU') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_MP'))
                                    AND sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
                                    AND sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01'
                                    AND (sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' OR 
      sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL)                                        
             MINUS

    SELECT distinct  TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) AS SPAN_ID, TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS 
    MAINT_ZONE_CODE
                                    from  APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
                                    INNER JOIN APP_FTTX.transmedia@SAT tm  -- transmedia added
                                    on sp.RJ_SPAN_ID = tm.RJ_SPAN_ID
                                    WHERE length(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = length(tm.RJ_SPAN_ID)
                                    and sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = tm.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE
                                    and sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = tm.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE
                                    AND LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21
                                    AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPN%') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPQ%') 
OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPR%')    
                                    OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPS%'))
                                    AND (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_BU') OR sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_MP'))
                                    AND sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
                                    AND sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01'
                                    AND (sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' OR 
sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL);

  NULL;
END FIP_VALID_TBL_TRANSMEDIA;
```

Please suggest what is wrong here

**UPDATE**

Table descriptiom

```
           Name            Null Type           
           --------------- ---- -------------- 
           SPAN_ID              NVARCHAR2(100) 
           MAINT_ZONE_CODE      NVARCHAR2(100) 
           UPDATED_DATE         DATE           
           UPDATED_BY           NVARCHAR2(100)
```

Comment: `ALTER PROCEDURE` can only be used if your procedure already exists. As a rule you you should use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` which works if your procedure exists or doesn't exist.

Comment: There are lots of questions already covering this; but what do you think the error message might mean? What do you expect to happen to the results of your query at the moment?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica: OK, got it.changed it accordingly

Comment: @AlexPoole: as u know, I am trying to create a SP then I will insert the record accordingly. So my first step is procedure creating

Comment: @AlexPoole: also its expecting into clause but as such i dont want it

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to do the insert within that procedure; or use the procedure to identify the records and insert them elsewhere (if so, where and how?); or why you want to involve PL/SQL at all. As I already asked, what do expect to happen to the results *at the moment* in the code you've shown? They aren't being consumed or output in any form right now.

Comment: Agree with @AlexPoole. FWIW, Steve Feuerstein has a nice article on the use of SELECT statements and cursors in PLSQL here, https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-cursors. This might be helpful in understanding the nuances of how to use them in PLSQL.

Comment: @AlexPoole:  yes i want to insert in this procedure only. that is what i m trying to say.. i have already created the table

Comment: running sql in a stored procedure...you have to tell the db what to do with the results, it's not like sql server where you can use sp's to run sql and have the results come back like a query

Comment: So you need an insert statement inside your procedure - you've previously been pointed towards the `insert ... select` syntax. But it isn't obvious why you'd put this into PL/SQL at all.

Comment: @AlexPoole: yes I want to insert the data of the procedure. its because this procedure will run on  basis and the data will get inserted into the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to insert in this procedure only

You can just use the `insert ... select` [syntax]:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIP_VALID_TBL_TRANSMEDIA 
 (
   POUTMSG OUT VARCHAR2
  )

 AS 
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO TBL_VLD_FIBERINV_DATA (SNAP_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE)
 SELECT TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID), TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE)
 ...
 MINUS
 SELECT TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID), TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE)
 ...
```

You don't need `distinct` with MINUS; and the column aliases aren't useful.

Or if you want to set the other columns, and they don't already default, you can include values for those in the query part - here using the system time and current user:

```
 INSERT INTO TBL_VLD_FIBERINV_DATA (SNAP_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, UPDATED_DATE, UPDATED_BY)
 SELECT TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID), TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE), SYSDATE, USER
 ...
 MINUS
 SELECT TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID), TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE), SYSDATE, USER
 ...
```

---

You need to execute the procedure for it to actually do anything; just creating or compiling it doesn't cause the code within it (i.e. the insert) to be run. You can do that from a simple anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
 OUTMSG VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
 FIP_VALID_TBL_TRANSMEDIA (POUTMSG => OUTMSG);
END;
/
```

You have to declare and pass a variable to match the procedure's formal argument, even though you don't currently populate that. (Hopefully you don't intend to catch exceptions and put the exception message into that variable...)

---

It seems a bit odd to be using `nvarchar2` in your target table, and to have the size as 100 even for user ID; and to have `to_char()` calls for what appear to already be strings. You're using [the  `to_char(char)` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-character.html#GUID-EC078E16-11FE-4ABE-AE05-DA9AC1B4BEBC) which always returns `varchar2`, so then putting that into `nvarchar2` seems strange...

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer, but getting error as `Error(10,2): PL/SQL: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns` tried your second answer

Comment: Did you change both branches of the MINUS?

Comment: nope, sorry.. i only changes one branch.. let me change the second one and check

Comment: the procedure is compiled succesfully now, but the records are not been getting inserted into the table

Comment: Well, have you *called* the procedure? Or just compiled it?

Comment: the message is coming like this `Procedure FIP_VALID_TBL_TRANSMEDIA compiled` also i run the script. still the data is not getting inserted

Comment: That message says the procedure is compiled, *not* that you've called it; what does 'also I run the script' mean - what script? Do you mean just this `create or replace`, or an actual call to it?

Comment: got it. acutally i was not running it. It is working perfectly fine now.. thanks a lot Alex. Also for your patience. Sorry for keeping you busy for silly mistakes. I am trying to learn Oracle. as this are all basic things. Once again thankyou so much

Comment: hi alex, now while calling this SP, getting error as `ora-22804 remote operations not permitted on object tables or user-defined columns`

Comment: @nkb - from your code it isn't obvious that you have any object tables or UDT columns, in either the source or target tables; and the target table (that you're inserting into) appears to be local. Presumably you've added more to your procedure now? Anyway, I think you should ask a new question showing your current code, how you call it, and that error; and include the table definitions and (if you do have any) UDT definitions for the both local and remote objects.

Comment: yes, sure.. i have modified my answer a bit according to the requirement. I will post a new question

Answer (score 1):

In this procedure you're executing a query but you're not putting the results of that query anywhere. I suggest rewriting as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIP_VALID_TBL_TRANSMEDIA(POUTMSG OUT VARCHAR2)
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT SPAN_ID || MAINT_ZONE_CODE
    INTO POUTMSG  -- puts result of query into POUTMSG
    FROM (SELECT distinct TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) AS SPAN_ID,
                          TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
            from  APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
            WHERE LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21 AND
                  (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPN%') OR
                   sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPQ%') OR
                   sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPR%') OR
                   sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPS%')) AND
                  (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_BU') OR
                   sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_MP')) AND
                   sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL' AND
                   sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01' AND
                  (sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' OR 
                   sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL)                                        
          MINUS
          SELECT distinct TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) AS SPAN_ID,
                          TO_CHAR(sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
            from  APP_FTTX.span@SAT sp
            INNER JOIN APP_FTTX.transmedia@SAT tm  -- transmedia added
              on sp.RJ_SPAN_ID = tm.RJ_SPAN_ID
            WHERE length(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = length(tm.RJ_SPAN_ID) and
                  sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = tm.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE and
                  sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = tm.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE AND
                  LENGTH(sp.RJ_SPAN_ID) = 21 AND
                  (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPN%') OR
                   sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPQ%') OR
                   sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPR%') OR
                   sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%SPS%')) AND
                  (sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_BU') OR
                   sp.RJ_SPAN_ID LIKE ('%_MP')) AND
                   sp.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL' AND
                   sp.RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INMUNVMB01' AND
                  (sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' OR 
                   sp.RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL);
END FIP_VALID_TBL_TRANSMEDIA;
```

Comment: The procedure seems ok, but I want to insert the data of `POUTMSG` in the table which is  `TBL_VLD_FIBERINV_DATA`. i have updated the table description in question

Comment: thanks for your SP, but any idea on how to insert the query data into the table. pls suggest

Comment: Please don't pose additional questions or modifications to the current question in a comment; instead, please ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: i m really sorry for that, but i was going step by step and it is my last step for achieving my goal. Though upvoted your answer for writing the  query